# How Do I Save Firebase Storage File URL in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created an html form for firebase using javascript. I have four text fields and a timestamp. I have an upload button that is properly storing a file (pdf) into firebase storage. I'd like to store the url of the file in firebase storage into a firestore database.

I've tried multiple ways to get the url and save it. My problem seems to be that the "destination: downloadUrl(signedUrl)," is not storing the signed urls of file but location due to the downloadUrl const. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing for the const to upload the actual url. I'm missing something in syntax and can't place my finger on it.

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form_data');
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
const downloadUrl = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/company_info.appspot.com/Client_Uploads/o/';

  //var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "Something",
  authDomain: "Something",
  databaseURL: "Something",
  projectId: "Something",
  storageBucket: "Something",
  messagingSenderId: "Something"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.firestore();
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

// saving data credit_union_referrals



form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton'); 

  var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader'); 

  fileButton.addEventListener ('change', async function(e) { 
  var file = e.target.files[0]; 
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('Client_Uploads/' 
   + file.name);
  var task = storageRef.put(file);  

  const uploadOptions = {
    destination: uploadFilePath,
    public: true
  };
  let uploadedFile = await bucket.upload(tempThumbFilePath, uploadOptions)
  const signedUrls = await uploadedFile[0].getSignedUrl({action: 'read', expires: '01-01-4499'})
  const publicUrl = signedUrls[0];


  })


  db.collection("firestore_category").add({
      lname: form.lname.value,
      inlineFormCustomSelect: form.inlineFormCustomSelect.value,
      additionalinformation: form.additionalinformation.value,
      acceptance: form.acceptance.value,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  destination: downloadUrl(signedUr),

})
  .then(function(docRef) {
console.log("Referral successfully sent!", docRef.id);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
console.error("Error sending referral: ", error);
  });
  form.something.value = '';
  form.next.value = '';
  form.additionalinformation.value = '';
  form.acceptance.value = '';

})
```

Expected results are that the url of the uploaded file will be saved to the firestore database. Instead, the file is uploaded properly but the url is not saved. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!